# Facebook share after like not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, google-plus, google-plus-one, facebook-likebox

Edit: +1 is working now.. only the facebook share is still broken

I've added some social buttons to this Website hgw-Hausnummern.de 
The +1 button doesn't work at all and the Facebook like button only works for simple likes, but if i want to share the site (from within that dialog you see after a like) this share doesn't show up in my timeline.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what's up with your Facebook Like button, but I do see one issue with your +1 button markup.

Your current +1 button markup looks like this:

```
<div class="g-plusone" data-size="small" data-annotation="none" data-href="www.hgw-hausnummern.de"></div>
```

You must specify the target website with a full URL. Try changing your code to:

```
<div class="g-plusone" data-size="small" data-annotation="none" data-href="http://www.hgw-hausnummern.de"></div>
```

Comment: thx for this hint.. i've just found that problem by myself :) i've simply removed the data-href attribute and it works lika a charme.